# Wordpress post cannot be opened via image

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

I wish you a good day.

on my website: https://www.eamovie.eu I can't open movies by clicking on a post image.

I have to click on the movie title.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

On `.video-thumb .video-image:after` add `pointer-events: none`

Right now the after element that is being overlayed on top of the image is preventing you from being able to click on it. By adding [pointer-events: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the after element you make all clicks pass through to whatever is below it.

Comment: I don't understand that at all. :(